# E-mail parsing addresses with junk characters

Tags: php, parsing, email, formatting

I'm sending e-mails through a form I coded and for some reason, for some cases the e-mail address becomes junk, and for other times it works fine.

```
//on form page
$message = str_replace("@e",$emtemail,$message);
```

$message is stored in SQL (defined on another page), same for $emtemail. $message is just the body of the e-mail being sent, and I'm replacing all instances of `@e` with the e-mail people send payments to. It sends one e-mail to the customer, and one e-mail to me.

```
//customer e-mail
//the display address might appear as payment52.62gmail.com instead of payment@gmail.com
//my e-mail
//all e-mail addresses formatted properly without error, @ appears as @
```

Why do e-mail addresses parse strangely? Something to do with encoding?

This is all of the code relevant to sending e-mails I have. I can't pinpoint the problem.

```
//any variables used in the below but not declared are previously initialized
$em = $userc["email"];
$subject = $emailone["subject"];
$subject = str_replace("@o",$ordernum,$subject);
$subject = str_replace("@u",htmlspecialchars($rn),$subject);
$subject = str_replace("@g",$gt,$subject);
$subject = str_replace("@sl","www.SZVapor.com",$subject);
$subject = str_replace("@ss","SZVapor.com",$subject);
$subject = str_replace("@st","SZVapor",$subject);
$message = nl2br($emailone["message"]);
$message = str_replace("@o",$ordernum,$message);
$message = str_replace("@u",htmlspecialchars($rn),$message);
$message = str_replace("@t",$table,$message);
$message = str_replace("@e",$emtemail,$message);
$message = str_replace("@g",$gt,$message);
$message = str_replace("@a",$addrsubmit,$message);
$message = str_replace("@sl","www.SZVapor.com",$message);
$message = str_replace("@ss","SZVapor.com",$message);
$message = str_replace("@st","SZVapor",$message);
$message = str_replace("@c",$em,$message);
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0"."\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"."\r\n";
$headers .= "From: no-reply@SZVapor.com";
mail($em, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Some examples of e-mail addresses given:

```
payment62.44gmail.com
payment54.45gmail.com
payment22.59gmail.com
payment25.49gmail.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

The first parameter entry for mail is the email address.

The code above does not do anything with $em

And by the way, I think that the last header line should look like this:

```
$headers .= "From: no-reply@SZVapor.com" . "\r\n";
```

Comment: $em is indeed defined in prior code, this is just the complex of stuff I use to replace strings. There's a problem somewhere in this code, disregarding the $em, $rn, etc defined earlier. Users receive e-mails (because $em is defined), it's just displaying e-mails within the body of the e-mail screws up.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue, and it was an error on my part. I was replacing all instances of certain character combinations with variables.

```
@g = replaced with grand total
@e = replaced with payment e-mail
@o = replaced with order number
etc
```

The order I did them in was such that I replaced @e with the e-mail payment@gmail.com, and then replaced all @g with the grand total, so payment**@g**mail.com became `"payment".$grandtotal."mail.com"`.